# JQuery: How to change active table class from another link?

Tags: jquery, tabs

I am using a JQuery to change between tabs. The issue I have is that in the first tab, it provides a set of category links to all the different tabs. Sort of like, you can go through all the tabs to find what you want or click on a link to go to a tab.

The links work on the page and take you to the correct tab. But it doesn't change the active state of the tab and remove the active state of the old tab. All it does is just change which tab is displayed. So the tab navigation doesn't change.

This first script handles the main actual tabs.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
    var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');

    // Show/Hide Tabs
    $('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).fadeIn(400).siblings().hide();

    // Change/remove current tab to active
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

    e.preventDefault();
});
});
```

This second script handles the links on the page that will open a specific tab without clicking on the tab button itself.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.tabs .tab-links1 a').on('click', function(e)  {
    var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');



    // Show/Hide Tabs
    $('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).fadeIn(400).siblings().hide();

    // Change/remove current tab to active
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');


    e.preventDefault();
});
});
```

I want it so that if I click on a link in .tab-links1 list it changes the class of the other list .tab-links so it removes the active state of the old tab and makes the open tab show as active.

Basically it is a link that is not actually clicking on the tab itself. It's a link inside the tab. I hope I am explaining this right.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post your code in fiddle or else post your html part?

Comment: Could you add the relevant HTML to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice is to create a function that handles the tabs.

For example:

```
function handleTabs(name) {
    /* Handle active state */
    $('.tabs li').removeClass('active');
    $('.tabs li.' + name).addClass('active');

    /* Handle visibility tabs */
    Code to handle the visibility
}

$('.tablinks a').on('click', function() {
    var tabname = $(this).attr('href').split('#');
    handleTabs( tabname[1] );
});
```

Html

```
 <a href="#tabname">Link</a>
```

With this approach you can handle the tabs from multiple places